# How to refer the same array for two different inputs

Tags: java

I am new to Java,I wanted to use the same method for different inputs

For Ex:

```
class a
{
 public void convert_array(String input)
{
/* Splitting input into integer array-Used some logics */  
int b[]=input;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
a obj=new a();
obj.convert_array(input1);//First Input String
obj.convert_array(input2);//First Second String
}
}
```

How to refer the array for first input and array for Second input.

Comment: you need to read up on returning values from functions

Comment: from what i understand you need to do method overloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1: you're not returning anything with convert_array (void).  If you want to return an array of integers then you need public int[] convert_array.

You probably want something like:

```
    class a{

    public int[] convert_array(String input){
            String[] intStringArray = input.split(",")
            int[] returnArray = new int[intStringArray.size()] //make it the same size as the split string 

        for(int i = 0; i < intStringArray.size(); i++){
                returnArray[i] = Integer.valueOf(intStringArray[i]);
        }
    return returnArray
    }

public static void main(String args[]){
a obj=new a();
int[] firstArray = obj.convert_array(input1);//First Input String
int[] secondArray = obj.convert_array(input2);//First Second String
    }
```

Comment: And, obviously, `input1` and `input2` need to be defined and initialized.